# Failure of the "Freshman's Dream"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are plenty of questions regarding the "freshman's dream", which holds for prime $p$: for all integers $x,y$,

$$(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p\text{ (mod $p$)}.$$

Many sources say it ALWAYS fails for composite numbers... but what's the proof? That is: if $n$ is composite, prove that there exist integers $x,y$ such that $(x+y)^n\not\equiv x^n+y^n$ (mod $n$).

Comment: "there exist $x$, $y$". There exist $x$ and $y$ in **which ring**?

Comment: It is tagged {elementary-number-theory} - but fair enough, I'll make the choice of $\mathbb{Z}$ explicit.

Comment: Look up Carmichael numbers.

Comment: It DOES fail on Carmichael numbers. I've checked.

EDIT: Apparently not closely enough. Nevermind.

Comment: "Many sources": which?

Answer (score 2):

Actually... I was mistaken. This statement doesn't fail at every composite number. In particular, it's actually true at every Carmichael number.

n is a Carmichael number if, for all integers $b$, $$b^n\equiv b\text{ (mod $n$)};$$ given this, it's clear that $(x+y)^n\equiv x+y\equiv x^n+y^n$ (mod $n$).

Comment: $(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p\text{ (mod $p$)}$ is true not only for $x,y$ integers. If $n$ is a Carmichael number it works only for $x,y$ integers.

Comment: @reuns When you discuss $(x+y)^p \equiv x^p + y^p \pmod{p}$ where $x,y$ are not integers, can you please state explicitly what $x,y$ are? I assume you mean something like: $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[t_1,\dotsc,t_k]$, polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (or maybe reduction modulo $p$ of polynomials with integer coefficients)? More generally elements in any commutative $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-algebra? Or something else?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Yes I'd say commutative rings of characteristic $p$ ie. commutative $\mathbb{F}_p$  algebras and commutative rings of characteristic $0$ where $p$ isn't a unit (like $\mathbb{Z}[t_1,\ldots,t_k]$). For Eric looking at $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is a good start.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/894193)

Comment: @5xum Fair enough. I've clarified my post to provide an answer to the question. (The first draft may have been written in some frustration that I thought I'd checked at the first Carmichael number before submitting...)

Comment: @reuns My question (and answer) both assumed we were working purely in the integers. If you'd like to contribute a thorough answer explaining both why my question's claim was false and what interesting things happen in these other rings, I'd be likely to accept it.